# Should i extend or use optional props when defining typescript interface for database rows?

Tags: typescript

I have an app with a database table "Department"

| id | external_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 345 | Sales |
| 2 | 123 | Economy |

A type definition for this could look like this:

```
interface Department {
  id: number;
  external_id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

And a function for getting department from the database could look like this:

```
function getDepartement(id: number): Department {
  db('department').getById(id)
}
```

Now, if i added another function for adding a department, which returns the newly autogenerated id of that department, it could look like this:

```
function addDepartement(department: Department): number {
  db('department').add(department)
}
```

In order for this to not throw any Typescript errors i would need to update the interface so that "id" becomes optional, since i don't have this when i add the department.

```
interface Department {
  id?: number;
  external_id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

It works, but that would also mean that whenever i use the type Department in my code i would need to check that id is actually defined, which is just noise in my mind.

This is a little contrived example, but hopefully you see the point i'm trying to make.

Would you instead use two interfaces where one extends the other?

```
interface DepartmentBase {
  name: string;
  external_id: number
}

interface Department extends DepartmentBase {
  id: number
}
```

Comment: Can `Partial<Department>` help you?

Comment: You can simply use the helper type `Omit` like this: `Omit<Department, 'id'>`

Comment: Thank you. All suggestions works, but in this case i would prefer the suggestion from @MrBar and use Omit as this maintains type safety better but still allows for the flexibility i was looking for :)